# Mongodb and mysql with php

Tags: php, mysql, json, mongodb

While optimizing database of one of our php + mysql project, I found that somewhere we have added JSON formatted data in mysql. If we see the JSON formatted data size is huge, alsmost 15% of the overall data. In this scenario, would it be good to use mongodb as a secondary database ? TO only store and process the JSON formatted data. Would it be a wise decisions ? Also would it improve the speed of operations ?

Comment: It's hard to fully judge from this information and answers will be opinion based. Mongo is excellent at handling JSON data so I would lean that way but not possible to know if you'd see any real improvements

Comment: Thanks Matt, Yes you are right I am mostly looking at the opinion based answer, Also I tried it for a sample project it seems to be working but I am not sure if I can use it for large database project. So I am yet researching on this big part.